# Start Steam in Big Picture mode by default

Tags: 16.04, steam

How can I get Steam to start in Big Picture mode by default when clicking the icon in Ubuntu 16.04?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Settings and then Interface *i think* then you can toggle "Start into Big Picture mode"